# Error read-only file system al levantar un contenedor docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, server, mkdir

Espero me puedan ayudar con el siguiente problema:

Tengo un servidor Ubuntu Server 20.04 en cual tengo docker. La instalación de docker la realicé tal cual dice el sitio oficial de docker, sin snap.

Tengo que instalar una imagen de openproject y lo realicé con el siguiente comando que está en el sitio oficial de openproject.

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/openproject/{pgdata,assets} 

docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name openproject \
  -e OPENPROJECT_HOST__NAME=openproject.example.com \
  -e OPENPROJECT_SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret \
  -v /var/lib/openproject/pgdata:/var/openproject/pgdata \
  -v /var/lib/openproject/assets:/var/openproject/assets \
  openproject/community:12
```

Al comienzo se instaló correctamente sin ningún problema y pude ingresar al sitio. Pero después de reiniciar el servidor e intentar hacer un **docker start** del contenedor me tira el siguiente error:

`Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/var/lib/openproject/assets': mkdir /var/lib/openproject: read-only file system Error: failed to start containers: openproject`

Ya probé desinstalando docker completamente y volviéndolo a instalar pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error cada vez que intento iniciarlo.

Investigué en montón de lugares cual puede ser la causante del error pero no existen soluciones claras. Generalmente vi que es un error cuando se instala docker con snap pero como dije anteriormente, mi instalación es limpia tal cual dice el sitio de docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esto ocurre por que el path esta fuera del alcanse del sandbox que crea docker:

```
/var/lib/openproject/pgdata:/var/openproject/pgdata
```

y

```
/var/lib/openproject/assets:/var/openproject/assets
```

Entonces buscando un poco por [aqui:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54492532/17161735) encontramos esta respuesta del sitio en ingles (Traduccion):

Es probable que sea un problema de ruta con Docker cuando se instala con snap, es mejor que lo instale con la documentación oficial de Docker.

Eliminar la ventana acoplable del complemento:

```
snap remove docker
```

Elimine el directorio docker y la versión anterior (está bien si aún no existen):

```
rm -R /var/lib/docker

sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
```

Instale el paquete docker oficial (si estas en ubuntu): https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Actualización: desde que publiqué esta respuesta, aprendí que las herramientas instaladas con snap se instalan en un entorno limitado con permisos limitados fuera de ese entorno limitado. Es probable que esta sea la causa, ya que la ventana acoplable no tendrá acceso al sistema de archivos externo desde su entorno aislado de espacio aislado.

Esta misma sugerencia se deja ver [haca](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63377239/17161735)